# How to check if a value is not equal using TeX conditionals?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, context, lua, context-mkiv

I have a value defined in a macro, e.g.:

```
\mymacro{apple}
```

I need to check if a value does not equal a string, e.g.:

```
IF #1 NOT EQUAL TO "apple" THEN
    PRINT "It is not a apple, it is #1."
FI
```

I have tried using this, but it does not work:

```
\ifx#1="apple"
\else
    It is not a apple, it is #1.
\fi
```

I have also tried using this, but it also does not work:

```
\startlua
    if #1 ~= "apple" then
        context("It is not a apple, it is #1.")
    end
\stoplua
```

- The macro might be set to any value.
- If anything other than "apple" appears inside, including TeX commands which do not create output, it should still be considered a negative result.

How can I create a plain TeX or Lua conditional which checks if the value is not equal?

Comment: You can wrap Lua string comparison inside a test: `\ctxcommand{doifelse([[#1]] == [[apple]])}{It is an apple.}{It is not a apple, it is #1.}`. This of course expands everything in `#1`.

Comment: Why not use ConTeXt [branching and decision macros](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Branches_and_Decisions).

Comment: Well, this was supposed to be a comment on the “Lua conditional” part of the question -- `doifelse()` deserves mention because you can evaluate arbitrary Lua code inside its argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ConTeXt provides a `\doif...` series of macros to do string comparisons. See the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Branches_and_Decisions) for details. For example, if you want check if `#1` is the same as a previously defined macro `\fakeapple`, then you can use:

```
\def\checkapple#1%
    {\doifnot\fakeapple{#1}
       {It is not an apple, it is #1}}
```

Comment: What is `\fakeapple` here? (I guess `\checkapplie` is a typo for `\checkapple`but couldn't figure out `\fakeapple`: is it a macro defined as the string "apple"?)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes, `\checkaplie` was a typo. I used `\fakeapple` because it was used in a previous reply by Phil Hirschhorn. I added some more details in my solution.

Answer (score 14):

You can define a command that expands to "apple", another that expands to whatever you want to test, and then use `\ifx`.  Here's a latex file that demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\appleref{apple}
\def\testit#1{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\appleref
    Yes, it's apple.
  \else
    No, it's #1.
  \fi
}


apple: \testit{apple}

pear: \testit{pear}

\def\fakeapple{apple}

fakeapple: \testit{\fakeapple}

\end{document}
```

Edit: tohecz points out in a comment that if you change `\def\temp{#1}` to `\edef\temp{#1}`, then `\fakeapple` (which is a macro that expands to "apple") would test as being equal to "apple".

Comment: If you wanted `\fakeapple` to pass the test as an apple, you could change `\def` to `\edef` in `\def\temp{#1}%` .

Comment: @tohecz: Yes, but I didn't want it to pass.  I used it to show that a macro expanding to "apple" is not treated the same as the actual string "apple".

Comment: I know. I've pointed it out just in case that somebody were looking for this variant of the solution ;)

Comment: @tohecz: Ah, I misunderstood.  Yes, it's a good thing to point out.

Comment: I should have said "If _somebody_ wanted ..." and it would be clear ;) Feel free to remark it in the answer itself ;)

Comment: One could modify the code to be plain tex by removing the `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}`, and changing the `\end{document}` into `\bye`.

Comment: Note that `\ifx` comparison is catcode sensitive, so it doesn't work if one of the strings uses 12 (other) instead of 11 (letter), which is the case of strings provided by TeX like `\jobname`. In this case you can use `\@onelevel@sanitize\@tempa` and the same for `\appleref` to make every letter catcode 12.

Comment: you really don't need LaTeX: this code should also work on Plain, right?

Comment: @erreka: That's right, this is all plain TeX, although it also works in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Under pdfTeX you can perform string comparisons using `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}`. From the [pdfTeX user manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf):

> `\pdfstrcmp{<general text>}{<general text>}` (expandable)
>
> This command
>   compares two strings and expands to `0` if the strings are equal, to `-1`
>   if the first string ranks before the second, and to `1` otherwise. The
>   primitive was introduced in pdfTEX 1.30.0.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\appleref{apple}
\def\testit#1{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{apple}=0
    Yes, it's apple.
  \else
    No, it's #1.
  \fi
}

apple: \testit{apple}

pear: \testit{pear}

\def\fakeapple{apple}

fakeapple: \testit{\fakeapple}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code should also work on Plain PDFTeX, right? So you really don't require LaTeX.

Comment: @erreka: Yes. You can use [this code](http://pastebin.com/aQrb9xm4).